# Add data to DataTable-Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I need to know how to add data from  database to DataTable-Bootstrap

This is my table:

```
<div class="container">
<button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
 <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
            <th>Column 3</th>

        </tr>
    </thead> 
</table>
</div>
```

I have a script that add from my database the data automatically to DataTable-Bootstrap

```
<script>
var tblusuario = document.getElementById('example');
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/');
//var databaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.database().ref('/users');
var rowindex = 1;

databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        var row = tblusuario.insertRow(rowindex);
        var cellIndice= row.insertCell(0);
        var cellId = row.insertCell(1);
        var cellNombre = row.insertCell(2);


        cellIndice.innerHTML=rowindex;
        cellId.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childKey));
        cellNombre.appendChild(document.createTextNode(childData.usuario));

            rowindex = rowindex + 1;


    });
});
```

**BUT THE TABLE DOES NOT RECOGNIZE IT**, I can't use the use the functionalities of DataTable

[See the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xy4o3.png)

After this, I have been studying for 3 days to change the code to put it in the table

I have took this reference(it's okey)

```
   <button id="addRow">Add new row</button>
   <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
   var t = $('#example').DataTable();
   var counter = 1;

   $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add( [
        counter +'.1',
        counter +'.2',
        counter +'.3',

    ] ).draw( false );

       counter++;
   } );

   // Automatically add a first row of data
   $('#addRow').click();
    } );
```

So far, I want to refactor my code in order funtion to dataTable

I have this, but it doesn´t work :(

```
<script>


$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#example').DataTable();
var counter = 1;
var databaseRef = firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/');
var rowindex = 1;
 databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
var childData = childSnapshot.val();

var addhere = childKey;
var b = childData.usuario;

            });
    });

  $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {

    t.row.add( [
        addhere,//PROBLEM
        'hola',
        '.3',
    ] ).draw( false );


   } );

  // Automatically add a first row of data
  $('#addRow').click();
 } );
```

Someone can help me with the code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By seeing your code it seems you are using [Firebase JavaScript client SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). So what you can do is retrieve the data from firebase and then inject it to DataTables.

```
databaseRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    data : snapshot.val()  
  });
});
```

You need to keep one thing in mind that data that is being send by the firebase should be in context with the [DataTables Data source types](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types)
, otherwise you have to use [columns.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.data) or [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) to modify the received data.

Comment: thank you very much. I thought that nobody would answer me anymore. Now I can see the firebase data to the table. Now I would like to place a button to the right of each row to eliminate the child. Any ideas?

Comment: @Vidal check [Generated content for a column](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/null_data_source.html)